# Adding text in a sentence using a Python for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, dynamic

I am trying to write a simple addition formula which should add a set of matrices based on start and end numbers.

Example:

I have following variables

```
startNum = 1
EndNum = 4
```

I would like my formula to be:

```
Matrix 1+Matrix 2+Matrix 3+Matrix 4

if 
startNum = 1
EndNum = 2
```

I would like my formula to be:

```
Matrix 1+Matrix 2
```

Can you please kindly assist me with this?

Comment: Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236. We can't "assist" you because there is no way to know what kind of assistance you need. The best way to fix this is to *try to write the code to solve the problem*, and then clearly explain what went wrong when you tried.

Comment: Thanks Karl,,, I will repost as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if I interpreted your question right because I'm not exactly sure what you're asking.

You have a list or array of matrices `matrices_list = [matrix_1, matrix_2, matrix_3...]`and you want to add some of them based on index. Each is a numpy array of the same shape.

```
import numpy as np    

new_matrix = np.zeros(matrices_list[0].shape)
for i in range(startNum, endNum+1): 
    new_matrix = new_matrix + matrices_list[i]
```

for `startNum=1` and `endNum=2` you will get `new_matrix = matrix_1+matrix_2`.

You may want to add a line to check if `endNum` is equal to or less than the length of `matrices_list`.

Comment: Thanks Thomas - I have a list of hundreds of matrices and I want to simply create a formula matrix which should add all the matrices between startNum and endNum. So instead of creating a list - I simply want to define a startNum and End Num and want a loop to create the formula... Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Ok. My method should work then, it will work for an arbitrarily large `matrices_list`. (your desired output is a new matrix the same size as the ones in the list correct?)